# How can I get that what this code in doing?

Tags: prolog

```
who([H|T], B) :-
   member(H, B), !,
   who(T, B).
who([_|_], _).
```

Can anyone explain what this code is doing

Answer (score 0):

This code is doing "NOTHING"

Comment: Not at all. It is succeeding always *except for* 1st argument the empty list or the 2nd argument not a list (or even an unbound variable). So it is the negation for empty list testing, kinda, sorta. It also goes into an infinite loop for `who(X,Y)` or even `who(X,Y)`, clearly a fiendish random program from the "exercise a Turing machine" folder.

Comment: There are more failures than you list: `who([x], [x])` fails although both arguments are non-empty lists. The relation *accepted* by this predicate is something like "first argument is a non-empty list where a (possibly empty) prefix composed of elements in the second argument must be followed by some element that is not in the second argument".

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie I bet you are some kind of AI. Quite precise indeed.